# How to access favorite questions from Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

The question was clearly worded in title. Is there any opportunity to access my favorites from Android? I found out the way to bookmark the question, but cannot find the way to access it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I did a search, but somehow didn't find this question